# Ubuntu Mate Raspberry Pi alongside Xenial on a Thinkpad?

Tags: thinkpad, mate, raspberrypi

I'm fairly new to Linux and programming, so if this is a crazy thought, sorry.

Is there a way to run Ubuntu Mate for Raspberry Pi on a thinkpad that is running Ubuntu Xenial?

My thought is to use the thinkpad to set up the miscro sd to have the RPi run simple tasks that might not require a screen or keyboard, mostly as a project.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run any software for a Raspberry Pi on a Thinkpad because of the different CPU instruction sets (ARM vs. Intel-x86-compatible).

However, you can

1. set up a virtual machine that emulates a suitable ARM CPU on any architecture,
2. allow the virtual machine to access the SD card,
3. install Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi onto the SD card from inside the VM,
4. modify and configure the system inside the VM to your liking,
5. shut down the VM, disconnect the SD card, and
6. finally use the SD card as boot medium for a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thank you much! Will this also make a way to set a user that is usable on the RPi?

Comment: Every modification you make to Ubuntu installation on the SD card will persist throughout a change of machine ‒ different virtual machine manager, different "bare metal" machine, different Raspberry Pi computer ‒ doesn't matter.